# What is wrong in this query ? I'm getting an error as "select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : '(', WITH"

Tags: mysql

My Query

error: **select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : '(', WITH**

```
    set @prev="SAME";
    select `date`, `COL1` , `COL2` ,
                if( `COL1`>`COL2` and ( (@prev="SAME") or (@prev="UP") ) ) then
                    "DOWN", @prev:="DOWN"
                else if( `COL1` < `COL2` and ( (@prev="SAME") or (@prev="DOWN") ) ) then
                    "UP", @prev:="UP"
                else
                    "SAME"
                END IF
                as 'sign' 
      from 
          temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `IF...THEN` within a query. You can use `IF(condition, truevalue, falsevalue)` or `CASE WHEN condition THEN value1 WHEN condition2 THEN value2 ELSE something END`.

`IF...THEN` is procedural syntax.

Comment: #Uueerdo @Uueerdo

I updated the query as you suggested

set @prev="SAME";
select `date`, `COL1` , `COL2` ,
  CASE 
    WHEN( `COL1`>`COL2` and ( (@prev="SAME") or (@prev="UP") ) )
    THEN
        "DOWN" , @prev:="DOWN"
    WHEN( `COL1` < `COL2` and ( (@prev="SAME") or (@prev="DOWN") ) )
    THEN
        "UP" , @prev:="UP"
    ELSE
        "SAME"
  END
                as 'sign' 
from 
       temp;

Error is still the same

Comment: The `THEN` part can only contain a single value, not multiple expressions. However, it looks like you should be able to just move your `@prev:= ` to before the CASE. As in `... , @prev:=CASE...`

Comment: #Uueerdo @Uueerdo
Is there any way to execute 2 expression under THEN part ?

Comment: There are hacky ways, technically there could be any number so long as the outermost expression only yields one value; something like `....THEN (SELECT 1 FROM (do a bunch of stuff in a subquery) AS hack LIMIT 1` could work, but I would not count a query using such a tactic to be reliable. _Either way, as I said in the previous comment, the query you've presented does not need such a hack._

Answer (score 0):

Following is the answer, it worked:

```
    set @prev="SAME";
    select date, COL1 , COL2 , 
      CASE 
      WHEN( COL1>COL2 and ( (@prev="SAME") or (@prev="UP") ) )
      THEN 
        @prev:="DOWN"
      WHEN( COL1 < COL2 and ( (@prev="SAME") or (@prev="DOWN") ) )
      THEN
        @prev:="UP" 
      ELSE "SAME"
      END as 'sign' 
    from
      temp;
```